# 2sxc custom template show preview icon or image

Tags: image, templates, icons, 2sxc

I created some additional template for the Content App but only some simple image is shown for those aditional templates.
See image:

[image]

Is there a way to add an image so the layout of that template can be shown like the other content templates which are added at installation?

Answer (score 0):

Most certainly :)

Just create a png file with exactly the same name - you can see how it's done in the default content.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel, I have done this and gotten it to work, but it can be quite frustrating to get DNN and whatever other caches cleared to get it to display. I think the existing method could be left for fallback, but since the feature of getting an icon to display is completely un-obvious. Worse you can trip over obscureness; you can name your cshtml file with a + sign (e.g. "_Content - Text + Circle image.cshtml") which works fine, but then the identical named PNG won't ever display.

It would be wonderful if you would just add a new field to the View definition and allow us to assign an image asset - just like everywhere else in the UI.

[image: Screenclip showing custom View icon]